# Need help turning a Lua function into a C#

Tags: c#

I'll need some help to turn a Lua function into a C # function. Here's what I did for now:

Function in Lua

```
function GetValueList()
    local List = {"value", "value2", "value3", "value4"}

    for a = 1, #List do
        print(List[a])
    end
end
```

Function in Csharp :

```
private static void GetValueList()
{
    string[] List = { "value", "value2", "value3", "value4" };

}
```

My big problem right now and I can not reproduce the loop of the code Lua in C#

Comment: I don't see where you've tried to reproduce the loop. Any C# tutorial can teach you how to do loops through arrays. Have you tried finding one?

Comment: I tried to search but I am unfortunately not found. I want to do for loop that retrieves the values ​​of the table and displays them one by one.

Comment: In C#, that's an array. Any web search engine can find a C# tutorial about working with arrays.

Comment: I found several methods to make loops but I do not know how to make the values be displayed one by one.

private static void GetValueList()
{
    string[] List = { "value", "value2", "value3", "value4" };

 foreach (string value in List)
 {
  Console.WriteLine(value);
 }
}

Comment: your foreach statement is already displaying one by one to the console. I just ran your code and all 4 values are displayed. https://dotnetfiddle.net/EEoc56

Comment: Yes indeed, sorry for the inconvenience. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help.

```
public static void PrintValues()
{
    var array = new  [] { "value", "value2", "value3", "value4" };
    foreach(var l in array) {
        System.Console.WriteLine(l);
    }
}
```